# Cooking Birthday Celebration

Tags: discussion

Did you know Seasoned Advice's anniversary of its graduation is coming up on **14 October**? Congratulations!

How about a fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events area a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) or at the [**Unix & Linux Birthday Bash**](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/a-contest-to-cleanup-old-abandoned-questions) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention through your moderator team! We're really interested in community-led initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “Let's go!”

Either way, congratulations on making it two years. :)

Comment: One really cool thing that one of our sites has done is organize an analog-space meetup. Feel free to get creative!

Answer (score 4):

Share your favorite birthday cake recipe. Or bake a Seasoned Advice-decorated cake and post pictures of it.

We can choose one of the ideas, then make a meta thread for it and let the community choose the best one, like Photo.SE's picture of the week thread. SE HQ can then send prizes to either community-chosen (highest voted) posts or judge the post quality themselves (a bit harder for non-bakers to judge the quality of a cake recipe without baking it, but I think that the idea counts - a chocolate/mint Battenberg is obviously different from a traditional Saher).

I know that there isn't much time left until the actual date, but we can *start* the competition on the 14th and let it run for a given amount of time (e.g. submissions start on the 21th, voting ends on the 28th).

If we go for the decorated idea, we can do a blog post as an offshoot of the competition - "the making of" Seasoned Advice first birthday cake.

Comment: It's [not about the cake recipe](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/24968/67) -- it's about how you decorate it: http://geeked.gsfc.nasa.gov/?p=5355  (which is why I asked the [question about whipped cream maker](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10885/67))

Comment: @joe maybe I wasn't clear. I suggested two separate ideas. One is to submit a recipe only (without the person submitting having to bake and decorate); the other to submit pictures of a decorated cake. The second is easier to judge, the first easier to produce and therefore more likely to attract enough entries for a competition to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't we get some stats to see where the the interests lie? A tag cloud maybe. Have users comment on their (least) favorite tag.

Or show some changes over time. Correlations between pumpkin related questions and Halloween. Etc.

Some of the most duplicated questions could be edited and put in the FAQ, or don't we put cooking questions in the FAQ?

Let's have a contest for the most poetic question or answer! For example [this one](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/27482/641) would be my favorite.

> You need to have a physical and mental connection with the wok as a soldier has a connection with his/her gun.

Or a polling question which question or answer was the most useful to the user.